# table structure

Tags: mysql

I am new to MYSQL i am working on message module. my table structure is that.

Message => id, message, created

MessageUser => id, message_id, receiver_id, sender_id, is_read

User => id, username, email

sender_id and receiver_id associate to User.id and message_id associate to Message.id

when i execute query for my inbox i put a condition ( WHERE receiver_id = $param);
same as for my sent item condition ( WHERE sender_id = $param);

its working fine.but **the problem is occoured when i delete a message** from my inbox or sent messages

bcoz i execute my delete query on UserMessage table.

when this message is delete from my sent box it is also remove from inbox of another user.

I have 2 soloutions

**1**. Add an other column is_delete and set its value on depending of deleting from receiver side or sender side.

**2**. divide the MessageUser table into two tables 
   Sender => id, message_id, sender_id;
   Receiver => id,message_id, receiver_id, is_read;

Tel me what is better solloution. and also tell me another solloutions

Thanks in advance 
please reply fast

Comment: Of the two you listed: Option 2 is better becuase option 1 would not meet the requirements you indicated: you would need to add 2 columns in option 1: one for Sender_Deleted, one for Receiver_Deleted.  However, I"m assuming there is always 1 sender and 1 receiver.. can there be a 1 sender and many receivers?

Comment: yes there can be 1 sender and multiple receiver..

Answer (score 0):

Option 3) consider the follwing:

User Table (Can be sender or receiver)
UserID PK

Message table (message or response)
MessageID (PK)
ParentMessageID (FK to self)

UserMessage table  <--You take action for deletions on this table. messages are kept intact until ALL userMesages are flagged as deleted for all parent & child messages.
SenderID
ReceiverID
MessageID
Status(Deleted, isRead, etc)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO I think the better way is to add a column with

> enum(sender,receiver,both) type.

If it is storing `sender` then it is deleted from sender, if it's value is `receiver` then it has been deleted by receiver and so on.